# addEditors to Document from formSubmit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm Working on creating script that will perform the actions described below.  so far, I've managed to get the first two parts to function, but am now stuck on getting anything more to work.  I've reviewed several response forums and tried the suggestions, but no success.

Desired script flow:
 form submitted from spreadsheet form
    completes fields:
        Timestamp
        Username (email collected on submission)
        Student
        Grade
        Intervention Plan
        Core Reading/Math
        Team (email list)

1  script runs onFormSubmit that then creates a copy of a template document, renames that new copy to the e.value "student" submitted in form,

2 then replaces selected text strings within the document with values submitted in the form.

3 Add editors to new document and sends notification with desired instructions

4 creates event (one week from submission date)     event details include instructions and link to shared document for team members to complete with their input, sends event invitation to email list.

Here is the working script so far.

```
function formSubmitValues(e) {

  var timeStamp = e.values[0];
  var userEmail = e.values[1];
  var student = e.values[2];
  var grade = e.values[3];
  var conern = e.values[4];
  var readingCore = e.values[5];
  var mathCore = e.values[6];
  var interventions = e.values[7];
  var team = e.values[8].toString(); // "just to be sure"..Henrique says add .toString      this allowed the replaceText part to work

  //Makes copy of template document and renames
  var tempID = ("1Rq0pDAnuGNfL6W3GB0ZuLeWM2uYzHpKzoyxoXlwjtgE") // use document ID from Template Document
  var copyId = DocsList
              .getFileById(tempID)
              .makeCopy(student + " Initial Referral") // names new copy as student's name
              .getId();

// trying to add editors to new document using email list generated in form submit value of "team"
DocsList.getFileById(copyId).addEditors([team]); 




// replaces text within template with selected fields from formSubmitValues
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId)  
  var body = doc.getActiveSection();

    body.replaceText("%STUDENT%", student);
    body.replaceText("%DATE%", timeStamp);
    body.replaceText("%TEACHER%", userEmail);
    body.replaceText("%TEAM%", team);

  return doc;

}
```

**REPORTED ISSUE RESPONSE:** Here is what they said: "The function takes an array or strings, like: `DocsList.getFileById(copyId).addEditors(['parent@domain.com', 'parent2@domain.com']);`

I tried entering emails directly into script like this and things worked. 
So my problem is not the '`addEditors` method, but lies in getting the form submitted emails to be passed correctly. Any suggestions on how I would do this?

I have tried what I believe to be all combinations of using     .toString(), or not, and using     .Split(',').

**RE-DEFINE PROBLEM  :** So it is an issue of how the emails are passed from the e.values form submit.

Here is where I'm at:
When I type emails into script directly: `.addEditors(['parent@domain.com', 'email2@domain.net', 'email3@gmail.com'])` it works, (I did have to move the `addEditors` method in the script to go right after the `.makeCopy` instead of at the end.)
This is what the Execution Transcript shows: 
`File.addEditors([[parent@domain.com, email2@domain.net]])` and it runs the rest of the script. note: One part I don't understand is the single quotes i.e. 'email'  They must be typed in the script, but don't show up on Transcript when run.  I've tried putting them around emails in the form, but it makes them show in Transcript and still doesn't run anyway.

So this is what script looks like now:

```
var tempID = ("1Rq0pDAnuGNfL6W3GB0ZuLeWM2uYzHpKzoyxoXlwjtgE") // use document ID from Template Document
var copyId = DocsList
              .getFileById(tempID)
              .makeCopy(student + " - TestingCopy") // names new copy as student's name + text
              .addEditors([team.split(',')])  
              .getId();
```

But when I use the `var team` with or without `.split(',')` it does not work. But in the Transcript it shows: 
`File.addEditors([[rreynolds@domain.net, parent@domain.com]])` 
which looks identical as to what shows when it does work, but that is the last thing shown in Transcript and editors are not added to document and the script does not finish.

I'm obviously not understanding something here.  Is there a way I could get the emails in the team e.values to be treated in a way that the addEditors method is requiring?  In the spreadsheet cell they appear as a CSV. i.e  rreynolds@domain.net, parent@domain.com
Do they have to be read one at a time, or something?

I'm learning a lot, and appreciate all your help.  I am sorry for the confusion with all the comments, but am not sure of the correct way to address issues in this forum.  For example: should I go back and edit my original script to show the current version, or add it someplace else? I'm trying to keep the conversation flowing, so that it is easier for others to follow - Thanks rob

Comment: Just got this to work for single email, but can't get it to work for multiple emails even when changed to addEditors(team) >>>DocsList.getFileById(copyId).addEditor(team);

Comment: team in your script is a string (with multiple emails ?), you should convert it to an array using team.split(',')

Comment: the var team is an e.value from a form submit.  It creates a string of emails separated by commas.  You logic makes sense.  addEditors is trying to add all emails as if they are a single email because they are a string not array.  So...where would I put the >>team.split(",")<<  When var team is used in body.replaceText it displays a list of emails separated by commas.

Comment: I tried it like this, but didn't work:    <<   DocsList.getFileById(copyId).addEditors([team.split(',')]); >>

Comment: You used it the right way (I guess :-) just not sure if the brackets are mandatory since the result of split is [email1,email2,email3].  I've make several tests but I don't get any results with docs... With spreadsheets it works exactly as expected, It seems there is probably a bug there ....

Comment: Reply from reported issue received: "Comment 3 by project member eric.koleda.devrel@gmail.com, Today (8 hours ago)
It appears you are passing in the email addresses incorrectly. The function takes an array or strings, like:

DocsList.getFileById(copyId).addEditors(['parent@domain.com', 'parent2@domain.com']);                                                   I tried entering emails directly into script like this and things worked.  So my problem lies in getting the form submitted emails to be passed correctly.  Any suggestions on how I would do this?

Comment: I saw that..., I had noticed that you forgot the array thing in the issue description. `teamasArray=teamasString.split(',');// assuming teamasString has commas between fields`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please let me give a last (hopefully) clear answer : (thanks for sharing the spreadsheet, this is far more easy to work on ;-)

here is your code fully working.

I have created some intermediate variables to show how it works.

```
    function formSubmitEditors(e) {

      // defines spreadsheet form events on submit of form.  This function formSubmitEditors is triggered on formSubmit
      var timeStamp = e.values[0];
      var fileName = e.values[1];
      var team = e.values[2].replace(/, /g,"|"); // remove unwanted spaces and commas replace by | for visibility ;-)
      Logger.log(team);// contains | as separators
      var teamArray = team.split('|');
      Logger.log(teamArray.length+'  :  '+teamArray);// check that it is an array of x elements

      //Makes copy of template document and renames
      var tempID = '1Rq0pDAnuGNfL6W3GB0ZuLeWM2uYzHpKzoyxoXlwjtgE' // use document ID from Template Document
      var copyId = DocsList
                  .getFileById(tempID)
                  .makeCopy(fileName + " - TestingCopy") // names new copy as student's name + text
                  .getId();                     // 
    var file = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).addEditors(teamArray);

    // replaces merged-text values within template with selected fields from formSubmitValues
      var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId)
      var body = doc.getActiveSection();

        body.replaceText("%FILE%", fileName);// you wrote %FILENAME% in place of %FILE%
        body.replaceText("%DATE%", timeStamp);
        body.replaceText("%TEAM%", team);// it will be shown with | as separators, if you don't like it replace team by teamArray.toString() to get commas again.
     }
```

EDIT : I removed the toString() for team event, not necessary since e.parameters are already strings.

EDIT2 : to be complete and do what you needed in the initial question you could replace the end of the code with this one that creates the Cal event on next week and sends invites with link to the doc.

```
  var file = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).addEditors(editorsArray);
  var fileurl = file.getUrl();
  Logger.log(fileurl)

// replaces merged-text values within template with selected fields from formSubmitValues
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId)
  var body = doc.getActiveSection();

    body.replaceText("%FILE%", fileName);
    body.replaceText("%DATE%", timeStamp);
    body.replaceText("%MAILS%", editors);

  var Cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('testencodage')[0];// replace with your calendar name you want to use
  var newEvent = Cal.createAllDayEvent('Fill the questionnary', new Date(new Date(newtimeStamp).getTime()+7*24*3600*1000), { guests : e.values[2] , sendInvites : true , description :"Don't forget to fill this document "+fileurl})
 }
```

Comment: Dude!!  You did it.  Merci beaucoup I don't really understand very well how the form event data is handled.  I'll need to study up and play with this some more.

Comment: just in case you don't notice, I added some features in the code ;-)

Comment: Ooops, there was an error in the edit : 'editors' is not in the right format anymore, use e.values[2] instead !

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a couple of things

1. Add a few Logger.log statements in your code to print out debug information.
2. Add a try ... catch block around the entire section of code and print out the exception. See if you are getting any exception.

Last, use the Execution transcript window to see where your script stopped, if it did.

Comment: Srik,  OK, I'm not completely sure how to do what you've suggested.  I've added some "logger.log" statements, but don't get anything in the view logs.  Could you explain further, or direct me to where I could find more guidance on doing this.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to add an editor by email : `addEditors([emailAddresses])` and `addEditor(emailAddress)`

The first has an "s" and needs an array of email adress strings, the second takes a single string as argument. You should use the second or add [brackets] to the email string in your code.

concerning you comment *// need to figure out where/how to:  .addEditors(email1,email2,etc);
  // is this done from DocsList or DocumentApp class?*

`addEditor()` and `addEditors()` belong to the [file class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file?hl=fr-FR), a member of DocsList class , you can add user(s) using **user(s) objects** or **user(s) email(s)** as explained in the doc.
It could be used like this `DocFile.addEditors([email1,email2])`

**EDIT :** A lot of comments on this post, sorry about that, it has become quite uneasy to read...  I tested these addEditors feature with spreadsheet and it works as expected, using simple array for multiple user emails and string for single email. The `document service` seems to have a problem with the `addEditor()` method and it should be reported to the issue tracker.

**REPORTED** I've reported [issue #1512](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1512) - Rocketrob

Comment: Serge,  I've added brackets like this>>>
  DocsList.getFileById(copyId).addEditors([team]); >>> to email list, but still not working.  In the Execution Transcript I get double brackets like this>>>File.addEditors([[rreynolds@teameureka.net, parent@rocketrob.com]])  >>> and no editors added, and the replaceText part no longer works.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: note that the current scripting works when only one email is selected. Double brackets are still shown in Execution Transcript, but editor is added and script continues to run.  Only when multiple emails (like shown in the previous comment) are added that things freeze up.  If it works with one, and muliple emails are comma separated, I don't understand why it's not working?  what I'm I missing?

Comment: the double brackets make me think that maybe you should use [[email1],[email2]]  not sure but can try ...

Comment: ok, Not sure how I'd do that with the "team" form variable, but to check your suggestion, I tried that by adding emails with brackets directly to script so it looked like you show above, but Still didn't work.

Comment: I've reported to issue tracker.  Any ideas on a work around for now?

Comment: Not that I know :-/  note : the function toArray() you use is not standard javascript, it's a prototype that works like this : `function toArray() {
    return this.split('');` and is not appropriate in this case.